# Docker build fails in GH Actions

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to run some NPM scripts, create a docker image and publish it on dockerhub.
I get this error trying to generate the image. It seems the second job doesn't see the build directory.

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat build/: file does not exist
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine
COPY    ./build/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/myapp/
EXPOSE 80
```

this is my workflow

```
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: App build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Npm install
        run: npm install
      - name: Npm build
        run: npm run build
  deploy:
    name: Docker image in DockerHub repository
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: build
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: LS
        run: ls -R
      - name: Login to dockerhub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Build Docker image
        run: docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t myaccount/myapp .
      - name: Push Docker image to DockerHub
        run: docker push myaccount/myapp:latest
```

Project structure

```
|   Dockerfile
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   webpack.config.js
+---.github
|   \---workflows
|           deploy.yml           
+---build  
+---src
```

**Update:** I changed my workflow to `ls` the whole GITHUB_WORKSPACE.

**`build` dir is actually missing** (the other files are there). Yet, the build process (the first job) ends without errors, and if I try to `ls -R` in the first job the `build` dir is there. It is missing in the second job.
**It seems the state of the workspace at the end of the first job is not available to the second job.**

Comment: Can you post your directory structure?

Comment: I added the project structure, thanks

Comment: It seems to be related to your Dockerfile syntax on line 2. Shouldn't it be something like `build/*` ?
There is this article that might also help to fix the specific error your related: https://jhooq.com/docker-copy-failed-no-source-files-were-specified/

Comment: @GuiFalourd I tried, I get another error..

Comment: I edited my quesiton again with more info, it seems `build` dir is missing indeed

Comment: The actions/checkout allows you to access files from the github repository where the workflow is located. I think the problem is that you divided your workflow in 2 jobs. Did you try to gather all the steps in only one job to see what happens?

Comment: Note: I know that you used the needs: build config in the second job, but I'm not sure it applies in this case when as it might perform the checkout from the current repo main branch, and not the one from the first job.

Comment: @GuiFalourd it works if I put everything in 1 job, but I would prefer having 2 jobs. Also, the real project where I want to implement this workflow is more complex than this toy project. About the Note you wrote: yes, I think that is part of the problem, I believe the checkout in the 2nd job is made from the main branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems for that you need `actions/upload-artifact` and `actions/download-artifact`.

```
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: App build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Npm install
        run: npm install
      - name: Npm build
        run: npm run build
      - name: LS
        run: ls -R
      - name: Temporarily save webpack artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: webpack-artifact
          path: build
          retention-days: 1

  deploy:
    name: Docker image in DockerHub repository
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: build
    steps:
      ## Build and deploy Docker images to DockerHub
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Retrieve built package
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: webpack-artifact
          path: build
      - name: LS
        run: ls -R
      - name: Login to dockerhub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Build Docker image
        run: docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t myaccount/myapp ./
      - name: Push Docker image to DockerHub
        run: docker push myaccount/myapp:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

2 jobs in Github Actions are run on 2 separate machines, so the second job cannot see the first one. The solution is to put them into one job.

```
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs: 
  deploy:
    name: Docker image in DockerHub repository
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Npm install
        run: npm install
      - name: Npm build
        run: npm run build
      - name: LS
        run: ls -R
      - name: Login to dockerhub
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USER }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Build Docker image
        run: docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t myaccount/myapp .
      - name: Push Docker image to DockerHub
        run: docker push myaccount/myapp:latest
```